# reference for QMetaObject::activate

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Searching all over the net, I found no references of QMetaObject, except for [this](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qmetaobject.html). This class has other methods as well. Who knows where to find all details about QMetaObject class?

Comment: What else do you need? That is the official documentation. Everything should be listed there.

Comment: @elusive No, it is not. For example, the method activate is not there.

Comment: Private methods should never need to be called, and are therefore not publicly documented. That is, unless you are working *on* Qt rather that *with* Qt, but then, you'd just need to consult the Nokia dev team for details on private interfaces.

Comment: For private methods like this, one will have to read the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all information about QMetaObject by downloading and reading the sources from https://doc.qt.io/. "activate" are 4 private static member functions of QMetaObject declared in qobjectdefs.h and are for "internal index-based signal activation".

Answer (score 1):

QMetaObject is about signal and slot mechanism. 
Look this

1. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/metaobjects.html#meta-object-system
2. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/metaobjects.html#qt-s-property-system
3. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/signalsandslots.html